# Can't load BIRT library

Tags: birt

I have a desktop application that uses BIRT. In the jar file I have a directory in resources's folder with the design and library files. Even they are in the same folder, when I run the application I get an exception showing that it can't find rptlibrary file:

```
Jan 31, 2013 11:29:33 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.model.core.LayoutModule loadLibrarySilently
WARNING: Syntax error found, and see error details.
Error.DesignFileException.SYNTAX_ERROR - 1 errors found! 
1.)  org.eclipse.birt.report.model.parser.DesignParserException (code = Error.DesignParserException.FILE_NOT_FOUND, message : The file "pdv.rptlibrary" is not found.)
```

If I change library tag in rptlibrary from:

```
<list-property name="libraries">
    <structure>
        <property name="fileName">pdv.rptlibrary</property>
        <property name="namespace">pdv</property>
    </structure>
</list-property>
```

to:

```
<list-property name="libraries">
    <structure>
        <property name="fileName">modelos_relatorio/pdv.rptlibrary</property>
        <property name="namespace">pdv</property>
    </structure>
</list-property>
```

it works but I got some errors when try to preview in eclipse, so, is there a way I can change this in code?

Answer (score 3):

What do you set your resource folder to in the designer?  This can be configured in the window->preferences.
[image]

You can configure it for the entire workspace or just for a specific project.  If you are using the API in your application, you should be able to set a resource path in your EngineConfig or set a specific instance of the IResourceLocator interface which really just requires two methods called findResource be implemented. You can look at the org.eclipse.birt.report.model.util.ResourceLocatorImplBase class in the source for an example.

Answer (score 0):

10 Years Later (French pronunciation)..
eclipse 2022.03 and BiRT 4.9.0

When you use eclipse/../preferences, don't type "report" to jump to the page cuz it will be not expandable (don't know why)
[image]

Whereas if as follows you just scroll to find it, you will do so

[image]

Finally I got the same problem regarding the not loading rptlibrary in eclipse & unit test (not webapp). This happened to me when I updated the birt tool to 4.9 Version. So, I just found that the path of the referenced library must be  relative to my "src" folder (due to this preferences I have)